# How to set cookies for 1 week in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to store 1 week cookies for login user, please help me for this.
I am using this function but how to set cookies for 1 week in this function please help.

```
function renew_wp_cookie() {

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $userinnow = $current_user->user_login;
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_set_auth_cookie($userinnow, $remember, $secure );
    }
    else wp_clear_auth_cookie();

}
```

Comment: Refer line number 647 of  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L0
.----If possible you can override wp_set_auth_cookies function and override expiration time according to your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Try this as a function or a plugin.

functions.php:

```
function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_week( $expirein ) {
   return 604800; // 1 week in seconds
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_week );
```

Or a simple plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Keep Me Logged In for One Week
Description: Sets a "logged in" cookie for one week.
Version: 1.0
License: GPL
*/

//Keep me logged in

function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_week( $expirein ) {
   return 604800; // 1 week in seconds
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_week );
```